# Removing page extension with .htaccess bugs Facebook Open Graph

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I researched for removing page extensions (Ex: **/page.php** to just **/page**) and I found this article: http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

So, I inputed this code into my **.htaccess** file. It really worked, but when I paste/type my index link at Facebook status with no trailing slash at the end, the Open Graph kinda bugs. There's no thumbnail, no right title and description.

Check it: http://www.aftercolors.com.br

Would the solution be remove the code from .htaccess and create subfolders with index files to have the pages without extension?

That's the code of my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: add your code to the question.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there. So people can easily see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one for just single link:

```
RewriteRule ^page page.php [L]
```

If you want just to redirect that one simple file. It's better to use id's to get bigger spectrum.